# Dose there exist a way to pass arguments not specified in advance to method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a new object of a certain class. I can do it this way:

```
user = Users(name=lst['name'],
             email=lst['email'],
             surname=lst['surname'])
```

`lst` is dictionary and each instance of `lst` could has diffrent fields. For example, it could look like this:

```
lst = {'name': 'John', 'email': 'john@mail.com', 'surname': 'Jang'}
```

but it can also look:

```
 lst = {'name': 'John', 'phone': '00000000'}
```

I want to make a function which will handle list as explained above. Is there exist a way to do it in python?

Comment: If all `lst` contains is those three keys, you can do `Users(**lst)`, which unpacks the `dict` into keyword arguments.

Comment: should not be reopened. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters and many others

Answer (score 1):

Just use some defaults, here I've used `None`s but you could provide some sensible default value for each:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None, phone=None, surname=None):
        print(name, email, surname, phone)

ls = {'name': 'name1', 'surname': 'surname2'}
```

and then unpack `ls` during the call:

```
User(**ls)
```

which will assign any keys that exist in `ls` to their appropriate arguments. You might also want to ammend `User.__init__` to grab any excess keyword arguments by using `**kwargs` in the function definition.